# How can I make these sentences active/passive?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I am having trouble turning these sentences into active/passive voice. I have tried but the active/passive meaning contradicts with the main meaning.

> **1. I saw him reading a book.(Passive)**
>   **2. Dr. Yunus was awarded the Nobel Prize for micro-credit system.(Active)**
>   **3. He was expected to be faithful.(Active)**
>   **4. It is time to close the door.(Passive)**
>   **5. Let me do it.(Passive)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passive voice of your first sentence will be:

> 1. He was seen reading a book (by me).

The second and the third sentences are written in passive voice. To make them active, you should change them to:

> 2. The committee (or anyone else) awarded Dr. Yunus the Nobel Prize  for micro-credit system.
> 3. Someone expected him to be faithful.

The passive voice of the fourth sentence is:

> 4. It's time for the door to be closed. (*considering it as an imperative sentence, you may also say "The door has to be closed now."*)

An imperative sentence has the following structure in the passive voice:

```
Let + object + be + past participle
```

So the passive voice of the last sentence will be like this:

> 5. Let it be done by me.  (or Let me be allowed to do)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I saw him reading a book.

The main verb, "saw", becomes "was seen"; the object "him" becomes the subject "he", and the subject "I" becomes "by me". So the result is: **He was seen reading a book by me.**

> 2. Dr. Yunus was awarded the Nobel Prize for micro-credit system.

This is already in the passive voice. If we want to make it active, then we change "was awarded" to "awarded", make "Dr. Yunus" the object, and add a subject: **Someone awarded Dr. Yunus the Nobel Prize for micro-credit system.**

> 3. He was expected to be faithful.

This is also already in the passive voice, so change "was expected" to "expected", make "he" the object, and add a subject: **Someone expected him to be faithful.**

> 4. It is time to close the door.

This sentence can't be put in the passive voice because the main verb is "is", which is a form of "to be", and the verb "to be" cannot be used in the passive voice.

However, as [helen's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/178791/2020) points out, instead of putting the entire sentence in the passive voice, it's possible to just put the phrase "to close the door" in the passive voice.

> 5. Let me do it.

[helen's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/178791/2020) describes how to put this in the passive voice.

Comment: "4. It is time that the door should be closed." If i do like this. Will it be correct ?