# How to change them from active to passive?

Tags: active-vs-passive

I m student to learn English and my teacher wanted to change the two sentences from active to passive:

1-They were teaching her English two years ago

2-Ali stayed at home to sleep because he was tired.

My Answer is

Her English was being tought two years ago.

is this right??

I can't solve the second sentence because  there is no object.

Any help ... thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm stuck changing active sentences into passive ones.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/206377/im-stuck-changing-active-sentences-into-passive-ones) Also [How can I make these sentences active/passive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178783/how-can-i-make-these-sentences-active-passive) and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that sentence (2) doesn't seem capable of being changed to the passive.

In (1), you are linking the wrong words together. *Teaching her English* means *teaching English to her*, so *her English* is not the object. It should be 'She was being taught English two years ago.'

Comment: Thanks.........................